# Java Program Never Completes to Print Count

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and count the number of lines in the file. Each line has a movie title. I commented out the line that increments count. If I uncomment the incrementing of count the program just hangs and never prints count. What am I doing wrong? It works fine if I just print each line in the while loop. But not if I try to increment count. Thank you.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class GuessTheMovie {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            File file = new File("movies.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            // open movies file and count the number of titles in the file
            int count = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                //count += 1;
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            // create String array of movies such that the size is equal to the number of movies in file.
            //String [] movies = []
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncommenting the line `//count += 1;` can not have  any effect on the `while` loop. This is simply not possible. Do you show us all the relevant code?

Comment: Can you provide the movies.txt file contents? `count += 1` should not have any effect here

Comment: My guess is that you removed the line calling scanner.nextLine(). If you do so, you never go to the next line, so it produces an infinite loop. You're not forced to *print* the next line. But you need to call the nextLine() method.

Comment: Your example actually works, even with `count += 1` uncommented: https://ideone.com/KHvShX

Comment: This works fine in both cases. Probably you are not going the next line in scanner.nextLine().
Can you share both the snippets of code - one that works and the other that doesnt

Comment: It seems you are commenting the line scanner.nextLine(). That can result in infinite loop

Comment: what's the output? do you see the printed elements inside the loop?

Comment: we need to know the content's of the file you are trying to read from, can  you add it on your question?

Comment: If there is no need to use it as algorithm, you could use `Files.readAllLines()` as it's shown below. So you just need to put `path` to the file and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't know how the `movies.txt` is formated i suggest you do the following:

- Append the contents to a `StringBuilder`
- Make a `String` with the contents of the `StringBuilder`
- Get the desired data

Here is a small demo , it works for me.

```java
//make sure you are using the "relative path" to find the movies.txt file(as follows)
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./movies.txt"))) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String responseLine = null;
       while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
       //By now you should have all movies & titles to your StringBuilder instance then

        String temp = sb.toString();
        String movies[] = temp.split(" ");//split the string at "spaces"
        System.out.println("First Element: "+movies[0]);
        System.out.println("Second Element: "+movies[1]);
        System.out.println("Third Element: "+movies[2]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file.");
 }
```

This is the content of my `movies.txt`

[image]

> Note: Split the `String` in a way that you get the the contents as you would like

- If you split it correctly the `movies.length` would give you **the number** of the movies

Follow this link and find out more about using the `split()` method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

**Output**

[image]

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class GuessTheMovie {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            File file = new File("movies.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            // open movies file and count the number of titles in the file
            int count = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                count += 1;
                scanner.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            // create String array of movies such that the size is equal to the number of movies in file.
            //String [] movies = []
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try, there is simpler way to interact with file:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

After that you could interact with a prepared list of all lines or get the count by using `lines.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I prepare working code for you. It is reading the file from filereader and st is the parameter which is equal to the each line. In loop it will go through each line and count the lines.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\test.txt");
         String st; 

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
         int count = 0;
         while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {

             count++;
         }
         System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```